# Way to do this using apply?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

I want to take an average for each row across different data frames. Does anyone know of a more clever way to do this using apply statements? Sorry for the wall of code.

Youl would need a vector of 1000:1006 for each `hiXXXX` file and then a vector 2:13 for the columns. I have used mapply for something weird like this before so maybe that could do it somehow?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(subavg)) {
    subavg[i,c(2)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(2)],hi1001[i,c(2)],hi1002[i,c(2)],hi1003[i,c(2)],hi1004[i,c(2)],hi1005[i,c(2)],hi1006[i,c(2)]))
    subavg[i,c(3)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(3)],hi1001[i,c(3)],hi1002[i,c(3)],hi1003[i,c(3)],hi1004[i,c(3)],hi1005[i,c(3)],hi1006[i,c(3)]))
    subavg[i,c(4)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(4)],hi1001[i,c(4)],hi1002[i,c(4)],hi1003[i,c(4)],hi1004[i,c(4)],hi1005[i,c(4)],hi1006[i,c(4)]))
    subavg[i,c(5)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(5)],hi1001[i,c(5)],hi1002[i,c(5)],hi1003[i,c(5)],hi1004[i,c(5)],hi1005[i,c(5)],hi1006[i,c(5)]))
    subavg[i,c(6)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(6)],hi1001[i,c(6)],hi1002[i,c(6)],hi1003[i,c(6)],hi1004[i,c(6)],hi1005[i,c(6)],hi1006[i,c(6)]))
    subavg[i,c(7)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(7)],hi1001[i,c(7)],hi1002[i,c(7)],hi1003[i,c(7)],hi1004[i,c(7)],hi1005[i,c(7)],hi1006[i,c(7)]))
    subavg[i,c(8)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(8)],hi1001[i,c(8)],hi1002[i,c(8)],hi1003[i,c(8)],hi1004[i,c(8)],hi1005[i,c(8)],hi1006[i,c(8)]))
    subavg[i,c(9)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(9)],hi1001[i,c(9)],hi1002[i,c(9)],hi1003[i,c(9)],hi1004[i,c(9)],hi1005[i,c(9)],hi1006[i,c(9)]))
    subavg[i,c(10)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(10)],hi1001[i,c(10)],hi1002[i,c(10)],hi1003[i,c(10)],hi1004[i,c(10)],hi1005[i,c(10)],hi1006[i,c(10)]))
    subavg[i,c(11)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(11)],hi1001[i,c(11)],hi1002[i,c(11)],hi1003[i,c(11)],hi1004[i,c(11)],hi1005[i,c(11)],hi1006[i,c(11)]))
    subavg[i,c(12)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(12)],hi1001[i,c(12)],hi1002[i,c(12)],hi1003[i,c(12)],hi1004[i,c(12)],hi1005[i,c(12)],hi1006[i,c(12)]))
    subavg[i,c(13)] <- mean(c(hi1000[i,c(13)],hi1001[i,c(13)],hi1002[i,c(13)],hi1003[i,c(13)],hi1004[i,c(13)],hi1005[i,c(13)],hi1006[i,c(13)]))
}
```

Comment: thank you for editing my wall of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are only 7 datasets, we can use that as arguments for `Map`, then `cbind` it, and get the `rowMeans`

```
Map(function(...) rowMeans(cbind(...)), hi1000, hi1001, hi1002, hi1003, 
                     hi1004, hi1005, hi1006)
```

Or use `+` with `Reduce` after getting the datasets in a `list` and then divide by the total number of datasets, i.e. 7

```
Reduce(`+`, mget(paste0("hi", 1000:1006)))/7
```

---

The second solution is more compact, but if we have NAs in the dataset, it is better to use the first one as the `rowMeans` have `na.rm` argument.  By default it is `FALSE`, but we can set it to `TRUE`.

Comment: `Reduce` solution is very nice. not possible to give double vote up :-)